# Extracting particular content(Scraping) from inside a tag present in div

Tags: php, html, screen-scraping

```
<div class="post_list_medium_widget">
    <div>
        <div class="feature-two-column medium-two-columns appear_animation left_post_align animate_css_stlye animate_start">
            <div id="post-22346"
                 class="post-22346 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-national">

                <div class="image_post feature-item">
                    <a href="http://www.news.in" class="feature-link" title="Ashamed to be human">
                        <img width="400" height="260" src="http://www.image.in"
                             class="attachment-medium-feature"
                             onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to extract the following information:

- Title, which in this case would be "Ashamed to be human"
- The image URL: http://www.image.in
- The content URL: http://www.news.in

How will I be able to do this in PHP. I have written something like this.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.url.in/';
$html = file_get_contents( $url);
libxml_use_internal_errors( true);

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('div') as $node) {
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "post_list_medium_widget")]');
    echo var_dump($node);
}
```

Comment: And what do you get with this code?

Comment: Is the data from which you want to parse your data, repeated or is it the only piece of code in the url?

Comment: This is only a piece of data @VermaJr.

Comment: @Jab so, you want to parse the data from only this piece of code? what i'm trying to ask is that if $html contains only this piece of code or this piece of code in a repeated manner?

Comment: yes. I want to know how we extract data from inside a div

Comment: Use Symfony DomCrawler: your life will be easier and you will be happier!